# HomeKit on iPhone can't find homekit simulator accessories?

Tags: swift, mfi, homekit, ios-homekit

I'm testing the HomeKit simulator and made a small app to get add Homes, get all the homes you've made and search for new accessories.

Now when i'm adding new accessories in the HomeKit Accessory Simulator i can only see them on the iphone simulator. Not on my real device after searching for new accessories.

Does someone has an idea why this happens, or is there a restriction that i need to know off, i have an MFi license if needed.

Thx.

Comment: NOTE: I am on the same WiFi as my Macbook Pro.

Comment: NOTE: It does work on my iPhone when i connected my Macbook Pro on my iPhone's hotspot network.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm running into the same problem.

Comment: @BevTheDev never found an answer.. sorry